# Rails templating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, template-engine

I would like to get some professional opinions about templating in Rails.

Right now we are building application and using many template helpers to render our views and lots of code looks like this:

```
content_tag(:div, link_to(image_tag('/'), 'url', :target => '_blank', :rel => 'nofollow'), :class => 'fancy-class')
```

Talking with other guys they say its perfectly fine with them to write html like that but for me it looks like this is how it was done years ago. (I'm not writing any backend, mostly work with frontend stuff and I came from asp.net/php/node.js)

Is this really "the good practice"/"rails way" to do it? Coming from any other language I suppose it's just controller who needs to format data mostly and then you just write simple html tags into view files filling them with variable names which already has something assigned to them.

Or this is just the way it works in rails and it's perfectly normal?

Thank you

Comment: Why didn't use partial ?

Comment: I ask the same question, but it seems that its normal in rails to do it this way, no?

Comment: It depends where, inside a model it's probably the best way to make some html. But inside a controller or an helper...use partial instead.

Comment: In most cases you should just use partials as Awea said. Also look at the [draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) for dealing with models.

Comment: It is normal to see that kind of code in helpers. Not in templates. The alternative is concatenated strings, which in a helper gets ugly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Rails way is to use the tag helpers when you're building HTML from within a helper method or presenter. They should not be in your partials. The intended use is to make a semantically named helper that outputs a tag. This helper receives options. You want to merge these options with some defaults and otherwise configure the tag before you output it. Rather than handle all this option building yourself, the tag helpers let you merge your options hashes together and send it all to content_tag. You should not be using them like building DOM documents in PHP or JS.